# Attaching database to my project

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

In my C# program I have a big problem:

I add an SQL server database named "Behgozin_DB" to my project. I do the following steps for adding the database:

1. In my SQL server management studio I detach my database
2. In my visual studio from Data menu I add new data source
3. My Connection String is:

> Data Source=(local);AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB_Behgozin.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Everything is OK but when I insert something into my database after closing the application , I can not see any data. But when I right click on my tables in my visual studio server explorer menu and choose show table data, my application reads the whole table of data completely!

Another problem is after working with this app, even it can not read its own data in table.

Its a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What kind of project is it? Which VS version? Which Sql server version?

Comment: its a C# project in Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server 2008

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed 1 hour ago. I answered it yesterday. It is a real question. I knew immediately after reading what is the problem since I encountered that many times. I think we must be more careful with closing if we don't have all knowledge,

Comment: yes amiram i'm agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database file has 2 copies. One is in your project and the other is in `bin\debug`. In design time you edit the one in your project. Each time your project changes and you build it, the project database file is overwriting the file in bin\debug, and this file you're updating in run-time.

In order to solve that you have three options:

1. Use only the file in bin\debug. Set the project database file copy options to "Never" (in the properties window), show all files of the project and add the bin\debug database file to the server explorer. Caution: If you accidently delete the bin\debug folder all your changes are gone. Manually copy the database file from bin\debug to the project folder when you change it.
2. Put the file in your sql server folder and not in your project. When deploying, change the connection string and copy the database from server.
3. Replace "|DataDirectory|" macro with the absolute path to the project database file. When deploying, just change it back to "|DataDirectory|"

Comment: Tanks it was so beautiful answare